# Make a parallel process by modifying my original code as little as possible

Tags: java, multithreading, forkjoinpool

I have this class:

```java
package metodo_java8_moderno;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SingleThreadClass {

    public List<Object> editAndAdd(List<List<Long>> matrix){
        Long limit = (long) matrix.get(0).size()*matrix.size()/2;
        List<Long> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0; i<matrix.get(0).size(); i++){
            for(int j=0; j<matrix.size(); j++){
                if(matrix.get(j).get(i).longValue() <= limit){
                    numbers.add(matrix.get(j).get(i));
                    matrix.get(j).set(i,null);
                }
            }
        }
        List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
        objectList.add(matrix);
        objectList.add(numbers);
        return objectList;
    }

}
```

I want to parallel only the following piece by exploiting all the cores of my CPU:

```java
            for(int j=0; j<matrix.size(); j++){
                if(matrix.get(j).get(i).longValue() <= limit){
                    numbers.add(matrix.get(j).get(i));
                    matrix.get(j).set(i,null);
                }
            }
```

I get an error and I believe it is due to the sharing of objects between different threads.

**I post all the code of my work:**

ElementMutator.java

```java
package metodo_java8_moderno;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface ElementMutator<T> {
    void apply(int i);
}
```

ForkJoinListMutator.java

```java
package metodo_java8_moderno;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction;

public class ForkJoinListMutator {

    public static final int DEFAULT_SEQ_THRESHOLD = 10000;

    private static final ForkJoinListMutator defaultInstance = new ForkJoinListMutator(ForkJoinPool.commonPool());

    private final ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool;

    public ForkJoinListMutator(ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool) {
        this.forkJoinPool = forkJoinPool;
    }

    public static ForkJoinListMutator getDefault() {
        return defaultInstance;
    }

    public <T> void mutate(List<T> list, ElementMutator<T> mutator) {
        mutate(list, DEFAULT_SEQ_THRESHOLD, mutator);
    }

    public <T> void mutate(List<T> list, int seqThreshold, ElementMutator<T> mutator) {
        MutateTask<T> mainTask = new MutateTask<>(list, seqThreshold, mutator);
        forkJoinPool.invoke(mainTask);
    }

    private static class MutateTask<T> extends RecursiveAction {

        private final List<T> list;

        private final int start;

        private final int end;

        private final int seqThreshold;

        private final ElementMutator<T> mutator;

        public MutateTask(List<T> list, int seqThreshold, ElementMutator<T> mutator) {

            this(list, 0, list.size(), seqThreshold, mutator);
        }

        public MutateTask(List<T> list, int start, int end, int seqThreshold, ElementMutator<T> mutator) {
            this.list = list;
            this.start = start;
            this.end = end;
            this.seqThreshold = seqThreshold;
            this.mutator = mutator;
        }

        @Override
        protected void compute() {

            final int length = end - start;

            if (length <= seqThreshold) {
                computeSequentially();
            } else {
                MutateTask<T> leftTask = new MutateTask<>(list, start, start+length/2, seqThreshold, mutator);
                leftTask.fork();
                leftTask.join();
                MutateTask<T> rightTask = new MutateTask<>(list, start+length/2, end, seqThreshold, mutator);
                rightTask.compute();
            }
        }


        private void computeSequentially() {
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                mutator.apply(i);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

ForkJoinListMutatorExample.java

```java
package metodo_java8_moderno;

import java.util.List;

public class ForkJoinListMutatorExample {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        GenerateMatrix generateMatrix = new GenerateMatrix();
        List<List<Long>> matrix = generateMatrix.generate(3,4);
        System.out.println(matrix);
        long t1 = System.nanoTime();
        SingleThreadClass singleThreadClass = new SingleThreadClass();
        List<Object> output = singleThreadClass.editAndAdd(matrix);
        long t2 = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("Time taken single thread process: " + (t2-t1)/100000000);
        List<List<Long>> newMatrix = (List<List<Long>>) output.get(0);
        List<Long> numbers = (List<Long>) output.get(1);
        System.out.println(newMatrix);
        System.out.println(numbers);
        t1 = System.nanoTime();
        MultiThreadClass multiThreadClass = new MultiThreadClass();
        output = multiThreadClass.editAndAdd(matrix);
        t2 = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("Time taken multi thread process: " + (t2-t1)/100000000);
        List<List<Long>> newMatrix2 = (List<List<Long>>) output.get(0);
        List<Long> numbers2 = (List<Long>) output.get(1);
        System.out.println(newMatrix2);
        System.out.println(numbers2);

    }

}
```

GenerateMatrix.java

```java
package metodo_java8_moderno;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class GenerateMatrix {

    public List<List<Long>> generate(int columns, int rows){
        List<List<Long>> matrix = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Long> row;
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
            row = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int j=0; j<columns; j++){
                row.add((long) randomGenerator.nextInt(columns*rows+1));
            }
            matrix.add(row);
        }
        return matrix;
    }
}
```

MultiThreadClass.java

```java
package metodo_java8_moderno;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock;

public class MultiThreadClass {


    private ReentrantReadWriteLock reentrantReadWriteLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

    public List<List<Long>> matrix;
    public void setMatrix(List<List<Long>> matrix) {
        reentrantReadWriteLock.writeLock().lock();
        try {
            this.matrix = matrix;
        } catch (Exception e){
            this.matrix = null;
        } finally {
            reentrantReadWriteLock.writeLock().unlock();
        }
    }
    public List<List<Long>> getMatrix() {
        reentrantReadWriteLock.readLock().lock();
        List<List<Long>> matrix;
        try {
            matrix = this.matrix;
        } catch (Exception e){
            matrix = null;
        } finally {
            reentrantReadWriteLock.readLock().unlock();
        }
        return matrix;
    }

    public int i;
    public void setI(int i) {
        reentrantReadWriteLock.writeLock().lock();
        try {
            this.i = i;
        } catch (Exception e){
            this.i = -1;
        } finally {
            reentrantReadWriteLock.writeLock().unlock();
        }
    }
    public int getI() {
        reentrantReadWriteLock.readLock().lock();
        int i;
        try {
            i = this.i;
        } catch (Exception e){
            i = -1;
        } finally {
            reentrantReadWriteLock.readLock().unlock();
        }
        return i;
    }

    public List<Long> numbers;
    public void setNumbers(List<Long> numbers) {
        reentrantReadWriteLock.writeLock().lock();
        try {
            this.numbers = numbers;
        } catch (Exception e){
            this.numbers = null;
        } finally {
            reentrantReadWriteLock.writeLock().unlock();
        }
    }
    public List<Long> getNumbers() {
        reentrantReadWriteLock.readLock().lock();
        List<Long> numbers;
        try {
            numbers = this.numbers;
        } catch (Exception e){
            numbers = null;
        } finally {
            reentrantReadWriteLock.readLock().unlock();
        }
        return numbers;
    }

    public Long limit;
    public void setLimit(Long limit) {
        reentrantReadWriteLock.writeLock().lock();
        try {
            this.limit = limit;
        } catch (Exception e){
            this.limit = null;
        } finally {
            reentrantReadWriteLock.writeLock().unlock();
        }
    }
    public Long getLimit() {
        reentrantReadWriteLock.readLock().lock();
        Long limit;
        try {
            limit = this.limit;
        } catch (Exception e){
            limit = null;
        } finally {
            reentrantReadWriteLock.readLock().unlock();
        }
        return limit;
    }

    public List<Object> editAndAdd(List<List<Long>> matrix){
        this.matrix = matrix;
        this.limit = (long) this.matrix.get(0).size()*this.matrix.size()/2;
        this.numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        int core = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        for(int i=0; i<this.matrix.get(0).size(); i++){
            this.i = i;
            ForkJoinListMutator listMutator = ForkJoinListMutator.getDefault();
            listMutator.mutate(this.matrix,Math.max(1,this.matrix.size()/(core*1+1)),(j) -> parallelFor(j));
        }
        List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
        objectList.add(this.matrix);
        objectList.add(this.numbers);
        return objectList;
    }

    public void parallelFor(int j){
        try{
            List<List<Long>> matrix = getMatrix();
            int i = getI();
            List<Long> numbers = getNumbers();
            Long limit = getLimit();
            if(matrix.get(j).get(i).longValue() <= limit){
                numbers.add(matrix.get(j).get(i));
                matrix.get(j).set(i,null);
            }
            setMatrix(matrix);
            setI(i);
            setNumbers(numbers);
            setLimit(limit);
            //System.out.println(">> "+this.matrix);
            //System.out.println(">> "+this.numbers);
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Errore!");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println(e.getCause());
        }

    }

}
```

SingleThreadClass.java

```java
package metodo_java8_moderno;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SingleThreadClass {

    public List<Object> editAndAdd(List<List<Long>> matrix){
        Long limit = (long) matrix.get(0).size()*matrix.size()/2;
        List<Long> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0; i<matrix.get(0).size(); i++){
            for(int j=0; j<matrix.size(); j++){
                if(matrix.get(j).get(i).longValue() <= limit){
                    numbers.add(matrix.get(j).get(i));
                    matrix.get(j).set(i,null);
                }
            }
        }
        List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
        objectList.add(matrix);
        objectList.add(numbers);
        return objectList;
    }

}
```

Comment: If you can swap outer and inner loop, you probably have much easier preconditions: as you never change the outer list, you simply could set up a threadpool where one thread handles one entry of the outer loop - this should doable in parallel very easy.
Problem with your solution is that you modify the inner list of `matrix` in parallel - you would have to sync this carefully, if you prefer to parallelize the loops in the order you have them now.

Comment: The code simplifies a much larger case study. No, I can't swap the outer loops. The thread pool is not good because if I have 10 columns in the main loop and my CPU has 40 threads I cannot use all the computing power of my machine. Yes I have to synchronize the matrix and I also think I did it correctly, I don't know any other strategies.